# What are the other j2me ergonomic technologies other than Polish and LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, j2mepolish, ergonomics

Are there other ergonomic technologies in j2me other than j2me-Polish and LWUIT ?

Comment: as far as I know in the mainstream there are no other technologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many Frameworks as explained [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_UI_Frameworks) , most of all works with j2me
but I recommend to use [lwuit](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lwuit/info), since its latest version 1.5 is used and much stable

Comment: @Nirmal-thlnkbeYond : Thanks ! Now I have a very wide choice :)